# How to handle errors properly when using HTTP client in Kotlin?

Tags: error-handling, kotlin, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have the following code, which contacts an external system (Capsule CRM) using Apache HTTP Client.

```
override fun findPartiesByUrlFragment(urlFragment: String): PartiesSearchResult {
    val req = HttpGet("https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/parties/search?q=${urlFragment}")

    req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${ApiToken}")
    req.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    val httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()
    val res = httpClient.execute(req)

    val parser = Parser()
    val json:JsonObject = parser.parse(res.entity.content) as JsonObject

    [...] // What happens thereafter isn't relevant because most errors are likely to occur in the code above

    return PartiesSearchResult(false, "", emptyList())
}
```

This piece of code must work in an application that runs 24/7, therefore I need to do right error processing and make sure that the entire application doesn't crash, if an expected problem (e. g. Capsule's server is down) occurs. `false` in `PartiesSearchResult(false, "", emptyList())` means that the operation failed.

I can chesk the HTTP response code and parse the response only, if it's 200.

But I'm confused because I don't see any declared exceptions here (as opposed to Java).

Now I want to do this:

```
override fun findPartiesByUrlFragment(urlFragment: String): PartiesSearchResult {
    var httpClient = null
    var res = null
    try {
        val req = HttpGet("https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/parties/search?q=${urlFragment}")

        req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${ApiToken}")
        req.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()
        res = httpClient.execute(req)

        if (res == null) {
            return PartiesSearchResult(false, "null response", emptyList())
        }

        if (res.entity == null) {
            return PartiesSearchResult(false, "null entity", emptyList())
        }

        val content = res.entity.content
        if (content == null) {
            return PartiesSearchResult(false, "null content", emptyList())
        }

        if (responseCode(res) == 200) {
            val parser = Parser()
            val json:JsonObject = parser.parse(content) as JsonObject

            [...] // Convert JSON to my own objects

            return PartiesSearchResult(true, "", emptyList())
        }
        return PartiesSearchResult(false, "Invalid HTTP response code", emptyList())
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        return PartiesSearchResult(false, toString(t), emptyList())
    }
    finally {
        closeIfNotNull(res)
        closeIfNotNull(httpClient)
    }

    return PartiesSearchResult(false, "", emptyList())
}
```

Is there a better way to do error handling in Kotlin (for the particular task of fetching data from another system using HTTP client), if my system must not fail because of expected problem situations (foreign server down, foreign server overloaded or having internal errors, temporary loss of internet connection etc.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options for better maintenance of this method. These options are not necessarily Kotlin specific. More like [Refactoring](https://refactoring.com/catalog/) and [Object design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). The one most obvious would be to split it into multiple methods. Since your method handles multiple different concerns you can split it into more focused pieces. Then thoroughly **test**, **errorproof** and **log** their behaviour.

For example:

- First part handles the HTTP GET request. Extract this to a method returning GET response and check for [connection exceptions](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html#execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)).
- Middle part could be extracted as a validation of GET response to make sure you got a valid data to work on.
- Last part is again separate concern of parsing JSON from GET response. Place for handling of parser exceptions.